# Angular 2 RC5 webpack source maps misaligned for debugging

Tags: google-chrome, debugging, angular, webpack, source-maps

Since upgrading to RC5, when debugging in Chrome dev tools, breakpoints are hit, but the debugger identifies the line as several to many lines later (in this case 15 lines!).  In the screenshot the "current" line is actually the line where `debugger;` is present.  This is making debugging very difficult.  This is in combination with webpack.  It works, but you have to interpret things manually rather than seeing exactly which line is executing.  It appears to only do this on my ts files, not on the angular code if I debug into it.

I'd love ideas on the source of this problem and how to fix it.

[image: Chrome Debugger]

Chrome 52

webpack 1.13.1 with `config.devtool = "source-map"`

If you set config.devtool to eval all is correct.  But any other value seems to have the offset issue.

Angular 2 RC5

Answer (score -1):

I was facing the same problem. The solution that was given to me was to uninstall the npm version of the angular-cli and reinstall the Github one by running the following:

```
npm uninstall --save-dev angular-cli
```

and then

```
npm i --save-dev github:angular/angular-cli#a8d7c0a9a0c1657db2a673c42bfbaa51fde2a466
```

Comment: It's the git hash. You are installing straight from their repository and specifying [which commit to install](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/pull/1686). At this moment, it just looks like it's their most recent passing commit.

Comment: I'm not using angular-cli at all.  We're working off of a webpack starter repo.  Using angular directly.  But maybe it's a post-RC5 build of angular that's really the solution?
WHERE did you get your answer, @PhotoPaul ?